# Import data from Excel File to Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have thousands of students records in Excel sheet. Now I will import that all data into Coradata [from Excel sheet to Coredata] and I will create my iPhone application using that coredata.

I don't have any idea, how to import Excel file data into coredata.

Comment: It looks like the accepted answer is that "this question is too broad". I think, therefore, the question should be put on hold for that reason: _Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once._.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're thinking to broadly.  You need to decompose this problem further.  Here's your real problem:

1. How do I read an Excel file into memory?
2. How do I create Core Data objects?

"Excel" has nothing to do with "Core Data".  They are entirely disjoint topics.

For the first question, there are several options.  You could try and find a library that reads .xls or .xlsx files directly, or you could require that the file be in a different format (like CSV or something).

For the second question, that's easily answered by reading the Core Data documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I would convert the file to xml.
There are plenty of codes showing how to parse xml.